# What is the interaction of ongoing effects targeting a monster weakness?

Tags: damage, pathfinder-2e, vulnerability

Trying to figure out how the *weaknesses* rules are applied and found an unclear interaction of using an emanation (aura) of a specific trait which a monster has a weakness to.

The interaction in question is between the [Angelic Halo](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=494) - 1st level focus spell for the *angelic* bloodline of the Sorcerer class - and the weakness to Good which a lot of demons have.

[Weakness](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=345) in itself states that

> If you have a weakness to something that doesn't normally deal damage, such as water, you take damage equal to the weakness value when touched or affected by it.

Does this mean that e.g. a [Quasit](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=97) with a weakness to Good 3 would take 3 damage every round while inside of that area? And if so, would it take this damage on its turn or on the caster's turn?

Looking for RAW if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, "Good" refers to a type of damage, so it doesn't fulfill the condition for a weakness to something that "doesn't normally deal damage." For example, a Quasit targeted with [Holy Water](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=245), an [Alignment Ampoule](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=852), or the [Divine Lance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=84) spell would take the 3 additional Good damage, but it wouldn't take damage simply from being in the presence of an aura with the Good trait. You might rule that it would still react to such an aura: for example, the quasit could focus its attacks on the source of the aura.

Answer (score 3):

@Rumel answers your specific instance correctly; Angelic Halo doesn't actually damage anything. But as for your general question...

## All damage instances can trigger weakness

The [Weakness rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=345) state, rather simply:

> Whenever you would take that type of damage, increase the damage you take by the value of the weakness.

An ongoing damage source, like [Sepulchral Mask](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=786), would trigger a creature's Weakness (in this case to mental damage) every time the creature takes damage from it. Similarly, persistent damage (such as the [Paladin's](https://2e.aonprd.com/Causes.aspx?ID=1) Divine Strike) triggers Weakness to Good damage every time the persistent damage triggers. This can lead to a lot of damage if utilized strategically, but it's generally accounted for in the creature's stat block already, so I wouldn't worry about it being too powerful.